# Why are nested immutable borrows disallowed in Rust?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Given how non-lexical lifetimes work, I don't understand why the following is disallowed by the compiler:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 10;
    let y = &mut x;
    let z = &x; // Immutable reference scope starts and ends here.
    println!("{}", y);
}
```

I understand that nesting (and by "nest," I mean the scope begins and ends without any invocations of previously defined references) a mutable reference could potentially invalidate previously defined references.  However, it isn't clear to me why an immutable reference can't be nested.

A commenter below responds:

> So the analysis remains local. You can't create a immutable reference to a thing whilst a mutable borrow is outstanding. That is a simple rule that can be easily checked.

I responded why this answer was not satisfactory to me, since the rust compiler performs more advanced checks than this already.

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 10;
    let y = &mut x;
    println!("{}", x); // error: immutable borrow occurs here
    println!("{}", y);
}
```

To me, perhaps naively, this indicates a capability that is sufficiently sophisticated enough to discern my special case described above since the compiler is already tracking borrow occurrences.

Additional clarity of question:

If the scope of an immutable borrow begins and ends inside the scope of a mutable borrow without any additional intermediate borrows, is there a concrete example for why this would be considered unsafe?  If this is provably safe, is there a reason why the compiler does not allow this?

Comment: Immutable references can be nested on their own. You just can't combine a mutable reference and an immutable reference. For the same reasons you can't combine mutable references.

Comment: I understand why, in general, you can't combine mutable references.  But that doesn't account for this special case.

Comment: how is it a special case? You have a mutable reference `y` from line 3 to 5. You can't create an immutable reference to `x` whilst that exists.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware.  The question still remains: Why.

Comment: So the analysis remains local. You can't create a immutable reference to a thing whilst a mutable borrow is outstanding. That is a simple rule that can be easily checked.

Comment: I'm sorry but you still haven't convinced me why this is a fundamental problem.  Not that I don't believe you, but your justification amounts to "it's just the way it is."  Also, if I remove the immutable reference and print x, I get a precise error indicating "immutable borrow occurs here."  The compiler seems sophisticated enough to pick precisely where borrows occur.  My particular special case doesn't seem any more advanced.

Comment: I'm really unclear what your fundermental question is. Is it why immutable and mutable borrows sourced from the same object as opposed to taking an immutable borrow of a mutable reference is disallowed, which does just come down to thats the way it is. Or is it something else?

Comment: Lots of things in the rust type system, especially around non-lexical borrows are that way because specific patterns were found to be useful, but no one has looked at other constructs in detail. Rust is a language that has developed iteratively through experimentation, not through someone setting out a spec in detail.

Comment: "Nonlexical lifetimes" still have a start and end (which your example crosses). You might be able to make an algorithm that just "figures it out", but it would probably be complicated and not performant. Might also not be possible; wouldn't be surprised if a "perfect" lifetime solver algorithm would be halting-problem-equivalent.

Comment: This is just how the ownerships rule work, as stated by [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html): "At any given time, you can have either one mutable reference or any number of immutable references."

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo This is closer to the type of answer I was seeking.  However, there is a lot to prove there in those claims.  As in the second code example above, how is the compiler able to determine that an immutable borrow occurred in side the scope of y?  This seems, at least superficially, to be similar to discerning whether an immutable borrow occurs inside the scope of z as in the first code example.

Comment: In your second example, the lifetime of `y`, a mutable reference to `x`, begins at its declaration and ends at its last usage (the second print). During that lifetime, you access `x` (the "immutable borrow") to print it, which is not allowed. You seem to be asking why the compiler can't know to swap the first print and the declaration of `y` for you. The answer is that it's very hard or impossible to do in the general case, and not really worth doing.

Comment: The two examples are, for these purposes, essentially identical: the expansion of the `println!` macro includes a borrow of each interpolated value, so both examples have `&x` at the same time as `&mut x` (which is fundamentally disallowed in Rust). Why is it disallowed? Because compilers and hardware make all sorts of optimisations for which programmers all too easily fail to  account, such as that when a value is read from `&x` it gets stored in registers and caches that become stale if/when the memory is modified through `&mut x`.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo No, my question has nothing to do with swapping anything.  It is about why can't the lifetime of an immutable ref be nested.  In my second example, if the prints are swapped, then everything works.  This indicates that the compiler knows when a borrow occurs inside the lifetime of y.  My question is, why can't this compiler ability be extended to the case of an immutable reference with a lifetime nested inside a mutable reference.  Such as in example 2 where everything would work as long as a borrow doesn't occur inside the lifetime of y (i.e., after swapping the prints).

Comment: @eggyal This is the only answer that has made any sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Rust's job to figure out where references are being used, as that would put way too much burden on the typesystem and make it impractical to use. So, Rust can't tell if the immutable reference was maybe sent to another thread, which is currently writing to the value while you're reading from it with the immutable reference.

Comment: "It's not Rust's job to figure out where references are being used."  I'm not going to debate where the compiler's responsibilities begin or end, but from what I can tell, the rust compiler attempts to do just this.  For instance, the errors given by the compiler tell me precisely where the borrow occurs and where the borrow is used. Additionally, the non-lexical lifetime seems precisely concerned with this, at least in some capacity.